# visual vm connection to remote weblogic

Tags: java, oracle

I think jmx is enabled on weblogic.  I the log I have

```
<Jun 3, 2015 12:14:08 PM CEST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141187> <Java     system properties are defined as follows: 
...
com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate = false
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port = 8888
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl = false
...
```

and I also see

```
<Jun 2, 2015 12:23:47 PM CEST> <Info> <JMX> <BEA-149512> <JMX Connector Server started at service:jmx:iiop://1.2.3.4:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime .> 
<Jun 2, 2015 12:23:47 PM CEST> <Info> <JMX> <BEA-149512> <JMX Connector Server started at service:jmx:iiop://1.2.3.4:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit .> 
<Jun 2, 2015 12:23:47 PM CEST> <Info> <JMX> <BEA-149512> <JMX Connector Server started at service:jmx:iiop://1.2.3.4:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime .>
```

But impossible have a connection with visual vm.

In the `add jmx connection` I tried with

```
1.2.3.4:7001
1.2.3.4:8888
```

with and without credentials.  But always the same result : `cannot connect to ...`

EDIT

Also tried with `jmap`.

Locally on the server with pid, it's working.
Using `localhost:8888`, it's not working.

Remotely, `jmap -permstat 1.2.3.4:888` gives me

```
Attaching to remote server 1.2.3.4:8888, please wait...
Error attaching to remote server: java.rmi.NotBoundException: Not bound: "SARemoteDebugger" (only bound name is "jmxrmi")
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: java.rmi.NotBoundException: Not bound: "SARemoteDebugger" (only bound name is "jmxrmi")
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.RMIHelper.lookup(RMIHelper.java:115)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.connectRemoteDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:517)
```

Comment: It might be only listening on the localhost interface, which means you need to use port forwarding or change the listening interface. Can you post the output of `netstat -an | grep 8888` on your server ?

Comment: tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN